# Fill NaN in pandas column in both direction

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas.fillna,

```
method : {‘backfill’, ‘bfill’, ‘pad’, ‘ffill’, None}, default None
Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill / bfill: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap
```

How can I fill values both backward and forward? None of the options seem to do this

Comment: .. If you have `[3, nan, 2]` and you do "both_backward_and_forward", what should the NaN be?  I don't understand what behaviour you want.

Comment: good point @DSM, that [ 3, nan,  2] case defn fails with both backward and forward. My problem is that I have a pandas column which starts off with a bunch of NaNs, and then some valid values and then again NaNs. The behavior I want is 'forward', but where 'forward' does not work, then 'backward'

Comment: perhaps, I can just do fillna twice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems very simple and there may be a quicker way, but simply chaining the two, like so

```
df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
```

This will fill forwards first and then backwards.

Answer (score 2):

Another option that may work for you is the `.interpolate` method, e.g.:

```
df.interpolate(method='nearest')
```

which takes the nearest value, effectively back- and forward-filling.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the precise result you are looking for and where are the NaNs in your dataframe. In the following situation you will see that only using two succesive `fillna` calls will actually pad the dataframe with values. The `interpolate` functions both fall short.

```
# Modules #
import pandas
from six import StringIO

# Define #
df = """ C   | Y   | S
         AA  | 10  | NaN
         AA  | 11  | NaN
         AA  | 12  | 52
         AA  | 13  | 53
         AA  | 14  | 54
         AA  | 15  | NaN
         AA  | 16  | NaN"""
df = StringIO(df.replace(' ',''))
df = pandas.read_csv(df, sep="|", header=0)

# Show #
print(df)
print('------------')

# This doesn't work (no propagation) #
df['S'] = df['S'].interpolate(method='nearest')
print(df)
print('------------')

# This work partially (propagation forward only) #
df['S'] = df['S'].interpolate(method='pad')
print(df)
print('------------')

# This works (propagation in both directions) #
df['S'] = df['S'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
print(df)
print('------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways how to achieve this but it also depends on your requirements and also on data types of columns to fill.

Example DataFrame (with numeric and object column):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "numeric": [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 4, np.nan],
        "object": [np.nan, "two", np.nan, "four", np.nan],
    }
)

# Out:
#    numeric object
# 0      NaN    NaN
# 1      2.0    two
# 2      NaN    NaN
# 3      4.0   four
# 4      NaN    NaN
```

The accepted answer by @RexFuzzle is completely fine, you can do `df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')` without any issue, but you can achieve the same with its synonyms, which is shorter:

```
df.ffill().bfill()

# Out: 
#    numeric object
# 0      2.0    two
# 1      2.0    two
# 2      2.0    two
# 3      4.0   four
# 4      4.0   four
```

You have also an option to fill a single value, e.g. `df.fillna("value_to_fill")`, but it's not what one usually wants especially when you have multiple columns and/or even different column types like in this example. But there is an option to provide a value for every column:

```
df.fillna({"numeric": -1, "object": "new_value"})

# Out[88]: 
#    numeric     object
# 0     -1.0  new_value
# 1      2.0        two
# 2     -1.0  new_value
# 3      4.0       four
# 4     -1.0  new_value
```

Another option is to use interpolation, but be aware most methods do support only numerical columns, it either does not change content of non-numerical columns, e.g. with object dtype, or even throw TypeError which is for example case of `df[["object"]].interpolate()` ->

> "TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all object-dtype columns in the DataFrame. Try setting at least one column to a numeric dtype."

[df.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) offers many methods and even some other options like `limit_direction` or `limit_area`. But it does not work always as expected since for example `df.interpolate(method="nearest", limit_direction="both")` will interpolate just elements surrounded by other values, the first and the last row in our case will be unchanged (NaN).

But you can use the default linear method (note that object column is unchanged):

```
df.interpolate(limit_direction="both")

# Out: 
#    numeric object
# 0      2.0    NaN
# 1      2.0    two
# 2      3.0    NaN
# 3      4.0   four
# 4      4.0    NaN
```

Or if you want to keep NaNs inside (e.g you would like to use different interpolation method for them), you can use `limit_area` parameter:

```
df.interpolate(limit_direction="both", limit_area="outside")

# Out: 
#    numeric object
# 0      2.0    NaN
# 1      2.0    two
# 2      NaN    NaN
# 3      4.0   four
# 4      4.0    NaN
```