# fill NA both directions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280094/fill-nan-in-pandas-column-in-both-direction) which is very simple.

However, in my code I have

```
final_df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Is it possible use both 'ffill' and 'bfill' and still modify the dataframe `inplace`?

I guess ultimately it would be nice to have something like `fbfill` or something

Comment: chain methods and replace the df: `final_df = final_df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')`

Comment: Yes thta is what I did. I was just wondering if chaining could work with `inplace`...

Comment: You should avoid using `inplace=True`, there is no real benefit

Comment: I thought it was more efficient

Comment: @Beck, `inplace` is applied only under the method it were invoked, it does not look for previous chains

Comment: @Beck not it's not, it's just a convenience

Comment: Then it's more confusing rather than convenient

Comment: Wouldn't a "fbfill" suffer from the same ambiguity as raised in the linked solution? Would we need a "fbfill" and a "bffill"?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/69591787/12846804

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, what I m seeking is not possible.
I thought it is more efficient to modify a pandas in chain with `inplace=True` hence my question but since this is not the case then saving it in an object the traditional way `final_df = ....` will be the optimal solution here.